# Cannot delete buttons using js

Tags: javascript

I can't delete two `<button>` tags using javascript. When you enter the wrong pin, I want the buttons to delete themselves but somehow it's not working.

```js
var radar = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var pin = 3778;
var pin_request = prompt("Podaj pin")
if (pin_request == pin) {
  document.write("Podany pin: " + pin_request);
  alert("Podano właściwy pin.");

} else {

  document.write("odmowa dostępu.");
  radar.parentNode.removeChild(radar);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    html {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 7em;
      display: block;
    }
    
    button {
      margin: 1cm;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body><br>
  <button>dodaj pieniądze</button>
  <button>zainwestuj w nieruchomości</button>
  <script src="do visual studio code.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Also sorry for half-English code.

Comment: Can't you just do `radar.remove()` ?

Comment: Check what value `radar` is. It'll give you a clue.

Comment: No, I tried probably every combination with child and remove elements but nothing seems to work. ( Ben Coupe)

Comment: @EmielZuurbier ah my brain autofilled the words after `document.getElementBy`

Comment: znam Twój pin, bój się! xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use querySelectorAll to get elements and in loop remove them.

```js
 var radar = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var pin = 3778;
var pin_request = prompt("Podaj pin")
if (pin_request == pin)
{
    document.write("Podany pin: "+pin_request);
    alert("Podano właściwy pin.");
    
}
else {
    
   document.write("odmowa dostępu.");
    radar.forEach(el=>{
       el.remove();
    })
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            html{text-align:center; padding:7em; display:block;}
            button{
                margin:1cm;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body><br>
   <button>dodaj pieniądze</button>
    <button>zainwestuj w nieruchomości</button>
    <script src="do visual studio code.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementyByTagName()` returns an array of elements, but `removeChild()` only takes one element as an argument. If you use a loop it should work:

```
var parent = radar[0].parentNode
for(var i = 0; i < radar.length; i++) {
    parent.removeChild(radar[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML5>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            html{text-align:center; padding:7em; display:block;}
            button{
                margin:1cm;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body><br>
   <button>dodaj pieniądze</button>
    <button>zainwestuj w nieruchomości</button>
    <script>
      var radar = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var pin = 3778;
var pin_request = prompt("Podaj pin")
if (pin_request == pin)
{
    document.write("Podany pin: "+pin_request);
    alert("Podano właściwy pin.");
    
}
else {
    
   document.write("odmowa dostępu.");
    radar.forEach(ele =>{
      ele.remove(); 
    })
}

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
 var radar = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var pin = 3778;
var pin_request = prompt("Podaj pin")
if (pin_request == pin)
{
    document.write("Podany pin: "+pin_request);
    alert("Podano właściwy pin.");
    
}
else {
    
   document.write("odmowa dostępu.");
   var elem = document.getElementById('btn1');
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    var elem2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
    elem2.parentNode.removeChild(elem2);
}
```

```html
<button id = 'btn1'>dodaj pieniądze</button>
    <button id = 'btn2'>zainwestuj w nieruchomości</button>
```